# Eagle PCB footprint specification for PAD-TESTPOINT

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I'm learning to use the Eagle PCB layout program. I selected a test point with the following specifications: SMALL THROUGH-HOLE PAD/TESTPOINT
Pad suitable for use as a test point (no pin)

Footprint: 1,6/0,8
THROUGH-HOLE PAD

Can some one please tell me the meaning of 1,6/0,8?

I assume the commas are equivalent to decimal points but I cannot find a definition of the two measurements (1,6 and 0,8). I assume one of them is a thru-hole diameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like pad and hole diameters - in Real Numbers, that is a .063 inch pad with a .031 inch hole - commonly used sizes on through-hole boards.